# Searching logical shards

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, sharding

Is the basic technique behind querying across logical shards just querying them all at the same time and consolidating the results?

There doesn't seem to be any built-in features of MySQL or Postgres that allows you to query across logical shards, so I assume you must query each shard or get some sort of software to sit in front of that database that indexes or queries for you.

Comment: sorry, i made it a bit more concise. hopefully that clarifies what i was asking. @bill-karwin's answer was just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is working on a new technology called [MySQL Fabric](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.4/en/fabric.html) to do this. It's still in early development (as of this writing). But they apparently intend it to be a built-in feature in MySQL 5.7.

You can also use [Shard-Query](http://shardquery.com/) today. This acts as a proxy to query across all your shards transparently. That is, you can write simple SQL queries as if you didn't have a sharded architecture. Shard-Query rewrites SQL and runs queries against each shard in parallel, then combines the results.

I don't know what, if any, solutions exist for PostgreSQL to automatically query across shards.